# How to integrate awsconfiguration.json file content directly in the code of my android studio app for security reason?

Tags: android, json, amazon-web-services, security

I am new to mobile development.
I have a mobile app developed using android studio.
This app stores files on Amazon server using awsconfiguration.json file json content for the server credentials.
For security reason, I need to remove the file awsconfiguration.json and move its content and read it directly from inside the code in java.
Is there any suggestion concerning this matter or do you have any other idea to secure this file ?
I will really appreciate your help.

Comment: I doubt it would be any more secure. That can be easily ripped out from the binary.

Comment: please can you explain more?

Comment: I am trying now to find a way to secure the awsconfiguration.json file in order to deny if someone find download the code using hacking tools to find this file so then he can find all the server credentials

Comment: If you move the credentials to the source code it still will be easy to read it from the binary. Either use tokens or setup the permissions correctly.

Comment: Ok Thank you Jakub. 
I will do some tests concerning your suggestions.